# Batch: Replacing a line by another line

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I know similar questions had been asked many time, but I cannot workout something fitting my needs...

So I have a file, containing a secret key, the line is starting like :

```
SECRET_KEY =
```

The secret key is a non-fixed length.

I want to find this line, to save it somewhere, to replace the all file containing the secret key by another file (very similar, but with a different secret key which I don't want), and to reintroduce the original secret key in the new file!

So for the moment I have this code:

```
echo Saving the actual SECRET_KEY...
findstr "SECRET_KEY" somefile.py > SECRET_KEY.txt
echo Copying source code files...
xcopy %~dp0\somepath %~dp0\someotherpath /EY
```

This part is working, as I have stored the original secret key in a text file, and replaced the file by another (together with other files, directories structures, etc...)

So now how can I find again the line starting by SECRET_KEY and replace the all line by the content of SECRET_KEY.txt?

EDIT:
I made some progress I think:

```
echo Saving the SECRET_KEY...
findstr "SECRET_KEY" inputfile.py > SECRET_KEY.txt

echo Copying source code files...
xcopy %~dp0\somepath %~dp0\someotherpath /EY

echo Restoring the SECRET_KEY...
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /I "SECRET_KEY" SECRET_KEY.txt') do set "secret_key=%%a"
echo !secret_key!
@echo off
set file=inputfile.py
set newline=!secret_key!
set insertline=23
set output=outputfile.py
(for /f "tokens=1* delims=[]" %%a in ('find /n /v "##" ^< "%file%"') do (
if "%%~a"=="%insertline%" (
echo !newline!
) ELSE (
echo.%%b
)
)) > %output%
```

I can then delete SECRET_KEY.TXT, inputfile.py, and rename outputfile.py into inputfile.py
Most likely not the most efficent way, but it works...

EXCEPT for one thing! I have a lot a special characters in this inputfile, that's why I used !secret_key! for example...

But I also have a lot of:

```
[some stuff]
```

and in the outputfile, it appears as:

```
[some stuff
```

So I guess I'm close, but I can't find a delimiter which will allow every single character to be outputed!

Comment: You need to read the file line by line by `for /F` and replace the secret-key line in the loop; I'd read the other file like that and write the output, so you have done the copying and the replacement in one go (so no more need for `copy`)...

Comment: I just edited the post, is it what you meant?

Comment: Almost, except that I though of checking each line against `SECRET_KEY` during being read by `for /F` and replacing it immediately, rather than replacing it using its line number, which you have to retrieve in advance by a separate file read operation; see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37054692) below what to see I meant exactly...

Comment: ...on the other hand, the method determining the applicable line number in advance is actually not that bad, because this seems the only way to avoid slow pipes, to make the script robust against all characters and to exclusively rely on `findstr` for all the search activities; due to these issues, I updated the script -- see [my edited answer](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/37054692/3)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following script reads the line containing `SECRET_KEY` from file `otherfile.py` at first; then it gets the number of the line of the input file `inputfile.py` where `SECRET_KEY` is placed; afterwards it reads the file `inputfile.py` line by line, check each line number whether it matches the previously found one; if a match is found, the previously gathered key from file `otherfile.py` is returned, so the line is replaced; otherwise, the line returned unedited; the output data is written to file `outputfile.py`:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "INFILE=inputfile.py"
set "OUTFILE=outputfile.py"
set "KEYFILE=otherfile.py"
set "KEYWORD=SECRET_KEY"

rem // Retrieve key from a file:
set "KEY="
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%K in ('findstr /L /C:"!KEYWORD!" "%KEYFILE%"') do (
    endlocal
    set "KEY=%%K"
    rem // Toggle delayed expansion inside of the loop to not lose `!`:
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    rem // `goto` ensures to take *first* key; remove it to take *last* one;
    goto :CONT_KEY
)
:CONT_KEY
endlocal

rem // Retrieve line number where key is found:
set "LRPL="
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "delims=:" %%M in ('findstr /N /L /C:"!KEYWORD!" "%INFILE%"') do (
    endlocal
    set "LRPL=%%M"
    rem // Toggle delayed expansion inside of the loop to not lose `!`:
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    rem // `goto` ensures to take *first* key; remove it to take *last* one;
    goto :CONT_NUM
)
:CONT_NUM
endlocal

rem // Move line by line from one file to another and replace key:
> "%OUTFILE%" (
    rem /* Use `findstr` to precede every line with its line number plus `:`,
    rem    in order no line to appear empty to `for /F`, as this ignores such;
    rem    the prefix (up to and including the first `:`) is removed later: */
    for /F "delims=" %%L in ('findstr /N /R "^" "%INFILE%"') do (
        set "LINE=%%L"
        rem // Extract the prefixed number of the current line:
        for /F "delims=:" %%N in ("%%L") do set "LNUM=%%N"
        rem // Toggle delayed expansion inside of the loop to not lose `!`:
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        rem /* Check current line number against previously retrieved one
        rem    and replace line in case of a match: *//
        if !LNUM! EQU !LRPL! (echo(!KEY!) else (echo(!LINE:*:=!)
        endlocal
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

Note that the `KEYFILE` and `INFILE` variables (defined at the top of the script) may be set to the same file path. However, `OUTFILE` must be different from `INFILE`; otherwise the referred file will be emptied.

This covers only the tasks of storing the `SECRET_KEY` line of a file to a variable and of exchanging the line containing `SECRET_KEY` in a file by the previously stored one and write the result to another file.

Comment: Thank you! I perfectly fits the purpose!