# find number set in text file, randomize and output new file

Tags: batch-file

In a batch file is this possible ?

I need to be able to identify, change and randomize 2 numbers `(X,Y)` in a text file with all other numbers to remain as they are, then to output to new file.

Each set either starts with a number `1` then a space or a number `2` then a space. The numbers I want to change start after this, then the numbers after I do not want to change.

Example set:

> ```
> 2 315710.13 222342.17 570.00 0.0 0 1 1
> 2 316563.21 222546.17 570.00 0.0 0 1 1
> 2 315378.85 222092.42 570.00 0.0 0 1 1
> ```

Example set:

> ```
> 1 267976.30 237345.12 360.00 0.0 0 1 1
> 1 272779.45 239386.46 360.00 0.0 0 1 1
> 1 269837.52 239266.38 360.00 0.0 0 1 1
> ```

Example to change:

> 2 **315710.13 222342.17** 570.00 0.0 0 1 1

The example numbers I want to change are in bold. These are the 2 numbers I want to change throughout the file. I want these numbers to randomize within a range of 1000 + or -.
Only these numbers I want to change and new file outputted with everything else unchanged.

Actual to change:

> 27_Static vehicles.artillery.Artillery$Flak18_88mm 2 **315710.13** **222342.17** 570.00 0.0 0 1 1

copied from a simulator file.

Comment: Do you have already some code?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: I can post some code later although I'm not sure how useful. The operating system is Win7. Thanks

Comment: I am using an adapted version from the following answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37045353/… from this i can get the keys " 1 " or " 2 " & replace 1st numbers after (x & not y) with new values but not second but what i need is to take both example numbers after finding the key/s, randomize them & replace them, then output new file. I have used this same code from answer for another batch which worked really well. I will post this adapted version once ive tidied it up

Comment: I already played with some code earlier. Perhaps it might help so I posted it. Since you are new here, enjoy a [tour].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "input=a.txt"
set "output=b.txt"

rem If defined, these sections will be modified.
set modify_sections="[NStationary]" "[Buildings]"

rem If defined, these sections will be ignored.
@rem Any section defined in modify_sections will not be ignored.
set ignore_sections="[MAIN]"

rem Loop through lines from input file and save modified lines to output.
set "section="
(
    for /f "usebackq delims=" %%_ in ("%input%") do (
        set "line=%%_"
        call :section
        if errorlevel 1 (
            call :ignore
            if errorlevel 1 (

                @rem Get 1st 3 tokens from the line.
                for /f "tokens=1-3* delims= " %%A in ("%%_") do (
                    set "a=%%A" & set "b=%%B" & set "c=%%C"

                    @rem Get tokens from the previous remainder.
                    for /f "tokens=1-4* delims=. " %%a in ("%%D") do (
                        set "d=%%a" & set "e=%%b" & set "f=%%c" & set "g=%%d" & set "h=%%e"
                        call :modify
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
) 3> "%output%"
exit /b 0


:ignore
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

rem Preset ignore_section default.
if defined modify_sections (set "ignore_section=1") else set "ignore_section="

rem Check if ignore this section.
for %%A in (%ignore_sections%) do if /i "%section%" == "%%~A" set "ignore_section=1"

rem Check if modify this section.
for %%A in (%modify_sections%) do if /i "%section%" == "%%~A"  set "ignore_section="

if not defined ignore_section exit /b 1

rem Ignoring line.
>&3 echo !line!
exit /b 0


:section
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

rem Check for section name.
if not "!line:~,1!" == "[" exit /b 1

rem Found section name %line%.
>&3 echo !line!
endlocal & set "section=%line%"
exit /b 0


:modify
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

rem d,f add or minus random number from original number.
if !random:~-1! gtr 4 (set /a "d+=!random:~,3!") else set /a "d-=!random:~,3!"
if !random:~-1! gtr 4 (set /a "f+=!random:~,3!") else set /a "f-=!random:~,3!"

rem e,g replace with random number and pad with 0 if needed.
set "e=!random:~-2!" & if "!e:~1!" == "" set "e=0!e!"
set "g=!random:~-2!" & if "!g:~1!" == "" set "g=0!g!"

rem Modified output.
>&3 echo   !a! !b! !c! !d!.!e! !f!.!g! !h!
exit /b 0
```

As batch-file cannot work with floats numbers, the `for` loop
will delimit on dot and space, which makes 4 numbers from the
2 float numbers.

Based on

> 27_Static vehicles.artillery.Artillery$Flak18_88mm 2 **315710.13** **222342.17** 570.00 0.0 0 1 1

`a.txt` is read line by line, and is not initially delimited.
A `call :section` will check if a section name from the
current line is detected, and will be saved to `%section%`
if true, and the line will be echoed immediately to file.

`%%_` is delimited to:

- `a` = `%%A` = `27_Static`
- `b` = `%%B` = `vehicles.artillery.Artillery$Flak18_88mm`
- `c` = `%%C` = `2`
- `*` = `%%D` = `315710.13 222342.17 570.00 0.0 0 1 1`

`%%A` to `%%C` is tokens `1-3` and `%%D` is token `*` which
is the remainder.

`%%D` is delimited to:

- `d` = `%%a` = `315710`
- `e` = `%%b` = `13`
- `f` = `%%c` = `222342`
- `g` = `%%d` = `17`
- `h` = `%%e` = `570.00 0.0 0 1 1`

`%%a` to `%%d` is tokens `1-4` and `%%e` is token `*` which
is the remainder.

The `for` variables are set to static variables
i.e. `set "a=%%A"`.

All tokens are, except `%%D`, are set to each of `%a%-%h%`.
`%d%` and `%f%` has a random number of 3 digits,
added to or subtracted from each of them.
`%e%` and `%g%` are each replaced by random
numbers of 2 random digits.

For handling of sections in the input file,
variables `%modify_sections%` and `%ignore_sections%`
exist so modification can be controlled by section.
If both are undefined, then all sections are modified.
`%modify_sections%` has priority over `%ignore_sections%`
and thus sections of `%modify_sections%` will always be
modified. `%ignore_sections%` can be useful if
`%modify_sections%` is not defined.

Each modified line is echoed to `%output%`. Stream 3 is
used for the echo to file, which means you can run the
script with `echo on` or add echoes into the `:modify`,
`:section` or `:ignore` label that will be printed to
console instead of to the output file.

Comment: The code you have written is working really well. Because i did not write the line as it exactly is your batch is also changing some of the original file that shouldn't, I apologise for not being clear in first post. Here is a complete line '27_Static vehicles.artillery.Artillery$Flak18_88mm 2 315710.13 222342.17 570.00 0.0 0 1 1 (Simulator file) Then with your batch it writes following to a new file '27_Static 205.84 -187.29 315710.13 222342.17 570.00 0.0 0 1 1'

Comment: So an original line 27_Static vehicles.artillery.Artillery$Flak18_88mm 2 315710.13 222342.17 570.00 0.0 0 1 1 Then processed through your batch with random numbers created (205.84 -187.29) Should then ideally process & change, then output the line to the new file like so... 27_Static vehicles.artillery.Artillery$Flak18_88mm 2 315915.97 222154.88 570.00 0.0 0 1 1 I will try to adapt it. Many thanks for efforts !!! amazing !!!

Comment: Updated your question and my answer with code and information to use actual data.

Comment: Really great !!! Its now very close, only that your newest code is removing all labels throughout the file and also most other text? It is leaving Capital only text / words & perfectly keeping the text within the lines to be changed. Again i apologise for not putting yet another piece of crucial piece of info, i did not realise it would matter. There are Labels throughout e.g. [MAIN], [SEASON], then there are also various pieces of text throughout e.g.  CloudType, playerNum, Searchlight . The example numbers (& text) to be randomized falls under a portion called [NStationary]. Many thanks !!!

Comment: I did try to adapt your original code but struggled although It did help me to understand some of how it works. Mostly i ended up with file/s b.txt with most correct but some text changed by many dots & the randomized numbers incorrectly changed & so my efforts were not so good. I will try to adapt your latest at least it will help me understand. Thank you for your continued help & again many thanks !!!

Comment: I hope this image may help : https://imgur.com/egVZfZo This is a simple sample .mis file & shows all the different portions including lines that need x,y numbers randomizing. Thanks again

Comment: Thanks for the image. It does certainly help to know the structure of the file. Updated the code with section detection and modify or ignore based on settings.

Comment: When processing .mis (image in prior comment) using your new code the result is so : https://imgur.com/pDxhJvO In your new code the [MAIN] section is set to be ignored but is still being processed ? I have tried to define the [SEASON] to be ignored but it also is being processed, is it because they also have "[" ? I'm trying to modify it. Each code / batch has given error for each line but seems to happily process all the same, the error is : '0' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file ".  Thanks, it is so close now !

Comment: The [NStationary] section is defined to be modified with randomize & also the [Buildings] section but the [NStationary] is not being processed with randomize. Thanks!

Comment: A `for` loop processing `"%%D"` could be an empty string so `:modify` was not being called to even get to the ignore|modify check. Moved ignore|modify check code into separate label so is called before the nested `for` loops. Sorry, give another try.

Comment: !Great!, almost perfect ! just one thing not processing correctly, where the lines have for example 'NORMFLY 73176.97 66313.01 500.00 300.00 **&0** The part **&0** is being removed in processed output file. I have tried to add this to ignore but no joy? +There is a tiny typo in your code 'set modify_sections="[NSstationary]" "[Buildings]" should be... ' set modify_sections="**[NStationary]**" "[Buildings]" ... other than this its really amazing !!!

Comment: Changed most variables to use delayed expansion as `&` expanded into the parsed source is interpreted as an special character. Delayed expansion helps to avoid this.

Comment: Its PERFECT !!! You have probably heard this before but really you have been amazing to do this, really incredible !, i am very grateful & others will be to. So many thanks :) !!!

Comment: Cheers, with pleasure `;)`.